# TypeScript cannot find module error

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]I am trying to use the template as a directive. For that, i am trying to import it to (app.module.ts). But I am getting an error " TS2307: cannot find module". Can anyone please help me to solve this error. I also uploaded some image.

[image]

```js
//app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ProductListComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

.....................................................

//product-list.component.ts

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html'
})

export class ProductListComponent { }

.................................................

//app.component.ts

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    // not quotes for template
    template: ` 
    <div><h1> {{pageTitle}} </h1>
            <pm-products></pm-products>
    </div>`
})

export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'ACME Product Management';
}
```

```html
<!--
product-list.component.html
-->

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Product List
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">Filter By:</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Filtered By: </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='table-responsive'>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Show Image</button>
                    </th>
                    <th>Products</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Available</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>5 Star Rating</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like `products` is not inside your `app` folder. It's one level higher so it cannot be found by the typescript compiler. The problem should be fixed by moving it inside the `app` folder.

Answer (score 12):

According to your directory structure, your `products` folder is one step down. You should try this import:

```
import { ProductListComponent } from '../products/product-list.component';
```

Or move your products folder inside your app folder

Comment: Why `./../` instead of just `../`?

Comment: ./ isn't necessary. ./../ is saying go up a directory, the current directory